# Xna Collision with wall 2D

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

[image: Sketch of scene]

Okay so I have been checking on the internet for an answer to my (some may say simple) collision detection problem. I have a car and I essentially want it not to drive through a wall or get stuck in it. I have tried to split the wall into four rectangles representing the four edges however it causes the car to move around in a very buggy manner.

Could someone tell me where i could find information or show me how to resolve the collision of a rectangular car with a wall as shown in the diagram? I want the car to carry on moving in a direction that does not cause it to go through the wall but like you normally would around it or away.

Comment: Is this like an AI problem, you want the car to automatically traverse obstacles?  Or simple collision detection, a user is controlling the car and they cannot pass through walls?

Comment: Could we see the relevant code?

Comment: Has your problem been solved or question been answered?

Comment: I wanted a simple colission detection so that the car would not enter the wall, i managed to get some headway using per pixel colission and checking colission overlap everytime the car moved by one pixel in any direction, i then would undo the move based on the offending direction of movement. this seemed however to be very consuming on cpu, in the end i decided to start using farseer which is great and i can focus on game logic and animation etc. I would appreciate any helpful pointers still especially on reducing cpu consumption and easy to follow code or tutorial.Thank you so much everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the [separating axis theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separating_axis_theorem).

You should ***really*** read this [tutorial](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) from the developers of N+. It has several interactive demonstrations so you can see the concepts that they describe.

[image: aabb]

Answer (score 1):

The car is able to hit the sides of the wall when:

```
CarYT > WallYB && CarYB < WallYT
```

If that's true it hits the left side when:

```
CarXL < WallXL && CarXR >= WallXL
```

The other cases are similar.

Comment: As @Henley's diagram shows, the second formula is only correct for cars and walls aligned with the axes.